# Maven Deploy failing to parse metadata

Tags: java, git, maven-release-plugin

Trying to upload changes to a private bitbucket repo and getting the following error :

```
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 6.538 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2017-09-25T12:40:40-04:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 24M/327M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-deploy-plugin:2.7:deploy (default-deploy) on project commonfiles: Failed to update metadata commonfiles:commonfiles/maven-metadata.xml: Could not parse metadata /path-to-maven-repository/maven-metadata-commonfiles.xml: unexpected character in markup < (position: END_TAG seen ...</versions>\n<<... @10:3) -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException
```

Opening the metadata file, I can see some Git-style head markups are making the XML unparseable.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<metadata>
  <groupId>commonFiles</groupId>
  <artifactId>CommonFiles</artifactId>
  <versioning>
    <release>0.3</release>
    <versions>
      <version>0.3</version>
    </versions>
<<<<<<< HEAD
    <lastUpdated>20170922183241</lastUpdated>
=======
    <lastUpdated>20170922184047</lastUpdated>
>>>>>>> 2eef4b2ec679542fd7e996341a0913500cd117df
  </versioning>
</metadata>
```

For reference, I am using the latest version of wagon-git and maven 3.3.9.

Previously I was seeing this error pop up occasionally and was able to fix by deleting the metadata file and deploying again. Have tried this several times now and nothing seems to change. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The file you are looking at has *unresolved conflicts* because of a pull you might have taken into your current branch.

You need to follow the steps:

1. Resolve conflicts in all the files which has conflicting code.

   ```
   <versioning>
        <release>0.3</release>
        <versions>
             <version>0.3</version>
        </versions>
        <lastUpdated>20170922184047</lastUpdated> 
        <!-- I've for example accepted the current change-->
   </versioning>
   ```
2. Commit and push the resolved change

   ```
   git commit -am "sample"
   git push origin <yourBranch>
   ```